# Get file from input type

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

We need to fetch xls file and get its content in json. I am able to do so but with hard coded xls file path like this:

```
    var url = "D:/ionic/Docs/Test.xlsx";
```

What I need to do is, select this file from html input tag and put it in `var url`. How can I do this ?

`Home.html`

```
<input type="file" accept="all/*" [(ngModel)]="getfile" (change)="onFileSelected($event)" id="fileInput"/>
```

`Home.ts` code:

```
onFileSelected()
  {
    var url = //what do I do here ;
```

Answer (score 2):

**For security reasons browsers are not allowed to access File System.**

Therefore Don't waste your time.

But you can read file data as below.

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)" accept="all/*"/>
```

**TS**

```
    onFileSelected(event) {

        let file = event.target.files[0];  

        let reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (e: any) => {
           let fileData = e.target.result;
           console.log(fileData);
        };
       reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-3k5xsh?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts)

Answer (score 1):

```
filename: string = '' ;
onFileSelected(event){
  let file = event.target.files[0];        
  this.filename= file.name;
}
```

You will get your file in **filename** variable.

Comment: this is getting the file name only, not the path, until i get that in `var url` it wont read xls

Comment: @user2828442 `not the path` means?

Comment: I used this code but it gives me `Test.xlsx` . But i want to get full path like "D:/ionic/Docs/Test.xlsx" and convert to json.

Comment: @user2828442 To get the full file path, you should call any method using web API.